# Как в Django отобрать объекты с заданным models.ImageField.url?

Tags: django

Есть модель с полем `image = models.ImageField` 
По id в views.py отбор элементов понятен: `self.model.objects.get(id=заданный_ид)`.
Как отобрать объекты, у которых изображение имеет заданный url? 
Вроде этого `self.model.objects.get(image.url=заданный_урл)`

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вот так: `self.model.objects.get(image_url=заданный_урл)`

Comment: Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так должно работать:

```
self.model.objects.get(image='заданный_урл')
```

Если результат пустой, `get()` вызовет исключение `DoesNotExist`.